# Using R to put a PDF file into an S3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I was able to put a pdf file in an S3 bucket using 'put_object' from the 'aws.s3' package. Basically, I moved a pdf file I had stored in my local machine to S3 succesfully but when I opened the pdf files in S3 they were all corrupted.

This is the code I'm using:

```
put_object('myfiles/myfile.pdf', 
  object = "myfile.pdf", 
  bucket = "myS3bucket")
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Should `myfiles/myfile.pdf` be in quotation marks?

Comment: How sure are you that the put operation corrupted the files? Have you checked that the original files are not corrupted? When you say "opened in S3" are you using a robust PDF viewer you trust or something built in to the S3 interface? Have you tried downloading one of the PDFs from S3 and opening it on your machine?

Comment: You are right John, I just forgot to put them when writing the minimal reproducible example. I actually got to put the files in S3.

Comment: Because I downloaded the files into my local first. After that I put them in S3. Files in my local are fine, but the ones in S3 aren't.